# How to fix blotchy deck

Tags: repair, deck, pine

2 year old pine deck was originally weathered for 6 weeks then 2x coats of Calbots Silver Beech Water Based Deck and Exterior Stain applied.

We did it ourselves and overall did a pretty bad job, my husband didn’t read the instructions to follow the advice of not overlapping and instead to run the stain the length of the boards. We also did it on a hot day so we have a bit of overlapping going on as well as what you can see in the photos, blotchy patches of colour and what looks like mould? We’ve tried a mould remover/deck cleaner to no avail.

How to fix?! Another darker coat?

Another product to strip it back?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may very well be able to lighten it up enough with an A/B (two part) wood bleach found in the paint section. The idea being that the bleach lightens the wood and removes enough dye that you can recoat with the same or slightly darker color. You definitely want to follow the instructions though, because the chemicals are quite harsh. Also try a small section first.

Answer (score 1):

Check the local hardware store paint department. Behr makes a series of deck products that are very good. They include a wood conditioner and mold remover, as I recall. These blotches are very hard to get rid of completely. I ended up restaining a deck once with a solid stain product to hide the black discolorations. Deck paint also works of course. I would investigate the latest wood deck reconditioner then stain or paint a solid color.